# Editor for PHP that find in the documents some strings (not sequentially)

Tags: php

I have recently edited some fields in my database, and now I'd like to know which php pages  access to database and use "those fields".

In my case, I'd like to know all page that contain `id`, `trackid` and `tracklist`.

Tried with Dreamweaver 8, but it finds only exact string, not all documents with those words.

Can you suggest to me another editor that can Do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Er.. I'm pretty sure that you can do a multi-file search in Dreamweaver 8, but pretty much all modern IDEs support this, a good *free* example being [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: Entire Current Local Site + Find All button should do it. Be careful not to accidentally click Replace All.

Comment: @Jared Must confess I don't have DW8 to hand, but that sounds pretty much spot on. :-)

Comment: @middparka - I use this all the time for what the OP is trying to do, for instance to find email address. I like DW's search, it's very friendly.

Comment: Ignore the replace all part: http://webdesign.about.com/od/dreamweaverhowtos/ht/dw_find_replace.htm

Comment: Yes, multi-file is guaranteed. But I can't find contemporaneously 2 words not sequentially... Eclipse can do it?

Comment: @markzzz You you want to find files that contain *all* of the words, use the regex option. (Pretty sure it's available in DW8.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all files with a certain string using the Eclipse-IDE. There is a [special version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr) for PHP. Press CTRL-H and go to the `file search` tab.